# what is distributed queue?

Tags: queue, distributed-system

**My Understanding :-** A distributed destination is a single, logical(not physical) destination to a client which internally contains set of physical destinations (queues or topics)  . 
It helps in scalable applications in terms of High availability(HA) and Load Balancing(LB).

So when i do  `distributedQueue.put(someObject)`, distributed queue will put the object on one of the phyicalQueue and also maintains some meta data to record which
object lies on which on which queue

Now when i do `distributedQueue.receive()` , it will refer metadata , poll the data from right queue and serve it to client.

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

That would be one way of implementing a distributed queue, yes.

However, in your implementation the metadata store will very quickly become a bottleneck/hot-spot.